# Why did my question get deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, moderation

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694053/google-chrome-extension-error) with the following contents :

> ### Google Chrome version (10.6):
>
> I am working on a plugin  it stopped working on MAC 10.5.8 
>   I ran Chrome with logging enabled and saw the following in the log file:
>
> [15465:2055:214114067914856:VERBOSE1:tab_contents.cc(1694)] Failed 
>   Provisional Load: `http://mysite.co...gic_osx_254.crx`, error_code: -3 
>   is_main_frame: 1 showing_repost_interstitial: 0 frame_id: 1 
>   what can be the problem ?

My question got deleted, and I didn't get any notification. Why not? Is it due to dummy site link that I used by mistake instead of example.com?

Comment: Yeah, I don't get it either. And by Jeff no less. Interested to see why

Comment: Probably, because it is off-topic

Comment: @YOU but why on earth would a question about plug-in programming be off-topic?

Comment: Formatting is odd, and the link looks "trojanish". Maybe it triggered some content monitoring script, and the deletion was of the better-safe-than-sorry kind.

Comment: @Pekka, the question looks like plugin is broken on his browser, not much looks like programming question?

Comment: @You `I am working on a plugin it stopped working on MAC 10.5.8 ` does not look like a programming question to you?

Comment: @Pekka's other trolling account
@Vivek, are you aware that your profile link points to a placeholder page?
sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: aha ok. I removed that.

Comment: I could edit the link (so it looks less "trojanish"), but couldn't vote to undelete because a blue diamond mod deleted it... Sorry.

Comment: Aw, but the placeholder page had the most popular girl on the internet :(

Comment: @Pekka, I saw that. But a quick read could miss that IMHO.

Comment: I've flagged it now asking for undelete - only moderator can do that so this is about the only option.

Comment: @Vivek in case you didn't notice, Bill just undeleted your question. If still relevant consider bumping it (e.g. starting a bounty) so it's back to the front for a while.

Comment: @Sha Dow Wiz Ard Thanks but I am no more looking for the solution of that question.

Comment: @Vivek oh, so why did you edit this question of yours (here on Meta) today?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd There was bot comment for community about removing broken link from the post. Editor automatically had made mysite as link. So today I just edit and removed that link.

Answer (score 8):

There is a (broken) link with **.crx** which is chrome extensions' extension, so I think Jeff thought that or someone reported that you are posting chrome exploit, by linking to a malicious/crafted chrome extension. So that could be the reason, why he deleted your post.

[image]

Comment: Or he just didn't like the formatting, or the lack of that! ;-)

Comment: @Arjan only lack of formatting :( .

Comment: Well, @Vivek, getting one poor question deleted is better than getting a total and permanent question-asking-ban. So, whatever the reason was for *this* deletion: please put some effort into your questions or soon you might find yourself at [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this). (My opinion *only* based on the example you posted above; but you want to read "How do I avoid getting a question ban?" from that link.)

Answer (score 6):

I don't see why this had to be mod deleted - it was probably a mistake.

The question has issues (such as the complete absence of code), but those are by definition for the community to handle, and possibly close.

Comment: @mario's comment above may be spot-on.  Possibly a better-safe-than-sorry script.  Note that it happened at approximately midnight Jeff's time (Pacific).

Comment: @David yeah, it was probably a mistake.

Comment: @^ so with what more information . 
should I repost my question ?

Comment: @Vivek if it's not life-or-death urgent, maybe wait to see whether Jeff or one of the mods undeletes it.

Comment: @ Pekka's other trolling account still waiting for response :(

Comment: @Vivek in that case, I don't think anyone can blame you if you post it again. If anybody gives you any trouble, point them to this question.

Answer (score 4):

And it was deleted by Jeff Atwood himself.  You must have really offended somebody :)

In all seriousness, though...

It doesn't say on the question, and maybe Jeff or a co-worker will be able to answer here, but my best guess would be the URL.  It's generally a good idea to mask those when pasting things into SO.  Two potential things wrong with that URL are:

1. It's broken.  This is both a good thing (doesn't make it a spam link) and a bad thing (it's a broken link).
2. If it was a full URL, it looks potentially spammy/phishy/etc.

Additionally, the question could use a lot more context and content about the plugin, including any code you've narrowed the problem to through your own debugging.

Comment: Also, *quickly* reading the question might make one think it's about *using* a plugin, rather than about developing one. But even when it's about developing, I doubt it's a useful question until some details about what the thing is supposed to do are added to the question.

Comment: @Arjan: Agreed, definitely.  Even if it wasn't deleted, it would be at high risk for being closed for exactly that reason.  It's pretty much impossible for us to help fix code we can't see.

Comment: @^ but s quick comment might not be use full , in place of deleting the message ?